How to place a qemu vm in background (it means that it should run between the processes but nothing should be shown on the screen)
I would like to run the qemu vm that you see below runs between the processes,so I don't want to see any monitor,graphic,terminal window,nothing should be shown on the screen.
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -machine q35 \
-cpu kvm64,hv_relaxed,hv_time,hv_synic -m 1G -nographic \ 
-drive file=Debian-warp.img,format=raw -rtc base=localtime \
-device usb-ehci,id=usb,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3 -device usb-tablet \
-device usb-kbd -smbios type=2 -nodefaults \
-netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap20,script=no,downscript=no \
-device e1000,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 \
-device ich9-ahci,id=sata \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file=/usr/local/share/edk2-qemu/QEMU_UEFI_CODE-x86_64.fd \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/usr/local/share/edk2-qemu/QEMU_UEFI_VARS-x86_64.fd

I tried passing the parameter -nographic : it is able to put the vm in background,but I'm not able to ping the ip number assigned to Debian,so something does not work within the vm. Instead,below you see what happens if I use the parameter -daemonize :

it presents two problems : 1) it does not ping and 2) I see that little window on the top left of the screen,that I don't want to see.
That vm is based on Debian 12 and starts with the grub manager. It waits for 3 seconds and if no keys are pressed,it boots the os. I've configured the automatic login of the user,so when it is authenticated,the script below is ran automatically :
function jumpto
{
label=$1

cmd=$(sed -n "/$label:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$') 

eval "$cmd"       

exit
}

start=${1:-"start"}

jumpto $start

start:

warp-cli disconnect

OLD_IP="$(curl -s api.ipify.org)"

sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.1.5 -j

MASQUERADE

warp-cli connect

NEW_IP="$(curl -s api.ipify.org)"

echo Connected to Cloudflare Warp...echo OLD IP is $OLD_IP ,

NEW IP is $NEW_IP

mid :

if [ "$OLD_IP = $NEW_IP" ]

then

echo OLD IP is $OLD_IP , NEW IP is $NEW_IP : it does not work

anymore,reconnecting...

sleep 10

jump foo

else

echo OLD IP is $OLD_IP , NEW IP is $NEW_IP : it still works.

sleep 10

fi

jumpto mid

foo:

warp-cli disconnect

OLD_IP="$(curl -s api.ipify.org)"

warp-cli connect

NEW_IP="$(curl -s api.ipify.org)"echo OLD IP is $OLD_IP ,

NEW IP is $NEW_IP : it works again.

jumpto mid

If,instead of -nographic, I use -vga std,the vm works as expected,but this is not what I want. I want that the vm runs hidden.


This seems to work for me:
qemu ... -nographic -serial none -monitor none &

But I would probably instead use a network serial console so that I can still access the console if necessary:
qemu ... -nographic -serial tcp:127.0.0.1:1234,server=on,wait=off -monitor none &


It  works if -vga std is declared,even if I also declare -nographic -serial none -monitor none & ; that's strange because I thought that -vga std is not compatible with -nographic ; but it seems it wants both...
